# BigQuery AdWords Transfer - Different Table columns across accounts

Tags: google-bigquery

I added all my AdWords Accounts via the automatic transfer to BigQuery. All AdWords tables are now in BigQuery. But today I realized, that the same tables from different accounts have a different column count.

Here one example:

- AdWordsAccount1.p_Customer_21530XXX --> 11 columns
- AdWordsAccount2.p_Customer_23450XXX --> 12 columns

In this example AdWordsAccount2 contains the "AccountTimeZoneId" (Description: 
Deprecated by Adwords API v201702. Please use AccountTimeZone instead). Why is this column missing in the other table?

It is only one example. Other tables like Campaign, AdGroup... have also a different column count.

I am looking forward for your help!